# css não funciona no nodejs

Tags: css, node.js, express.js, template, ejs

Eu estou tentando renderizar um template ejs com o node mas o css não está sendo aplicado, e não creio que seja problema no caminho do arquivo. Abaixo está o css.

```
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
vertical-align:baseline;
list-style:none;
border:0
}

.text h1{
color: red;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2AWW.png)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Recebe algum erro no console?

Comment: Olá! Sugiro alterar sua questão para Português uma vez que está postando nesta versão do StackOverflow.

Comment: Não apareceu arro algum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma diferença entre a estrutura de diretórios que você vê em seu server express para a estrutura de diretórios enviada para o cliente, que contém todas as informações do HTML pra ser renderizado. A pasta public é o diretório base para esse tipo de arquivos, então no seu index.ejs o href do link deve ser css/style.css . Faça essa mudança e tudo deve estar funcionando.